# Avg of a Sum in one query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum, average

I would like to know if I can get the average of a sum in one single SQL SERVER request,

Have tried to do it with the following request but it doesn't work:

```
  SELECT t.client, 
         AVG(SUM(t.asset)) AS Expr1
    FROM TABLE t
GROUP BY t.client
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the avg of clients assets?

Comment: The avg of the sum of the assets of every clients

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I think your question needs a bit of explanation. If you want to take the sums grouped by `t.client` you can use:

```
SELECT t.client, SUM(t.asset)
FROM the-table t
GROUP BY t.client
```

Then, if you want to take the average of this sume, just make:

```
SELECT AVG(asset_sums)
FROM
(
    SELECT t.client, SUM(t.asset) AS asset_sums
    FROM the-table t
    GROUP BY t.client
) as inner_query
```

You can't however group the outer query, because this will give you results like in the first query. The results from the inner query are already grouped by `t.client`.

Comment: what's a ? after the last Parenthese ?

Comment: It's a nickname for the inner query. Every inner query have to have the name.

Comment: I think you need to change avg(t.asset) to avg(inner_query.asset)

Comment: add you'll need to alias sum(t.asset) as asset

Answer (score 21):

Its very simple

for ex.

```
 SELECT t.client, 
         SUM(t.asset)/count(t.asset) AS average
    FROM TABLE t
GROUP BY t.client
```

in "average" you will get average of "t.asset"

Comment: Wow, perfect example of a much easier solution. Sometimes I love math!

Comment: @Kalpesh  How to get `SUM of AVG of t.asset`.?

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to get the average assets of clients I think I would use at CTE.  You can try if sql 2005 or greater

EDIT:
Took the second group by out as I think you want just one result here of average assets

```
With clientsum (client,assets)
as
(
    SELECT     CLIENT, SUM(asset) AS assets
    FROM         CLIENTTABLE
    GROUP BY CLIENT
)
SELECT avg(assets) AS Expr1
FROM  clientsum
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sum(avg(value) from * tablname
```